# Как добавить второй маршрут по умолчанию

Tags: cisco

Не совсем сюда пишу возможно. У меня простая реализация vpn на windows server. Два сетевых интерфейса. Внешний смотрит наружу и на нем прописан маршрут по умолчанию. На внутр интерфейсе добавлены несколько маршрутов вручную к некоторым сегментам внутр сети. Если я убираю маршрут по умолчанию на внешнем интерфейсе и прописываю маршрут только к шлюзу этого внешнего интерфейса, то клиенты снаружи не могут подключиться по vpn. Почему? ведь vpn клиентам достаточно знать маршрут только от внешн интерфейса и до шлюза этого интерфейса, а дальше шлюз провайдера смаршрутизирует все пакеты куда надо.

Comment: **Если я убираю маршрут по умолчанию на внешнем интерфейсе и прописываю
маршрут только к шлюзу этого внешнего интерфейса,**
А я вот тут не понял, что означает "маршрут только к шлюзу этого внешнего интерфейса"? Как он выглядит? Возможно, ваш сервер не знает куда отправить ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из вашего "витиеватого" описания проблемы... Лучше схемку для понятности.

Шлюз по умолчанию. - шлюз для пакетов, которые не подходят под другие заданные маршруты.

Когда вы убираете "маршрут по умолчанию" компьютер сравнивает, есть ли для пакета "определенный маршрут", и отбрасывает его, когда видит, что он не принадлежит ни одной известной ему сети.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть вам подойдет Плавающий статический маршрут?
Для этой цели плавающий статический маршрут настраивается с более высоким значением административного расстояния, чем основной маршрут. 
При настройке плавающего статического маршрута необходимо использовать более высокое значение административного расстояния, чем для EIGRP.
К примеру EIGRP 90 AD
Плавающий статический маршрут - 95 AD
При утрате динамики будет работать Плавающий статический маршрут!